# TrustArc JavaScript Implementation

Tags: lightning

Trying to Implement TrustArc within Lightning Component but running into issues with Locker Service.

Here's my code within the component:

```
<div id="consent_blackbar"></div>
...
<div id="teconsent"></div>
```

Here's my code within my component helper: I'm not able to load the script file as a static resource because the script is dynamicaly generated with a unique ID from the TrustArc source (consent.trustarc.com). That's why I'm including it like this.

```
({
    loadExternalScript: function(){
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "//consent.trustarc.com/notice?domain=f5.com&c=teconsent&js=nj&noticeType=bb&text=true&gtm=1";
        script.setAttribute("async", "async");
        script.setAttribute("crossorigin", "");
        head.appendChild(script);
    },
})
```

Here's what the script does. The script gets the element 'consent_blackbar' and allows for a modal window to open (show users a place to review and accept/reject the cookie settings that are being used). The second thing it does is finds the 'teconsent' element and inserts a 'Cookie Preferences' doing a similar thing: allows for modal window to open when use clicks the newly inserted 'Cookie Preferences' link.

The Locker Service, which I cannot disable, is preventing the third part TrustArc script from manipulating the dom. Is anyone else using TrustArc to manage privacy compliance for the GDPR, CCPA, and other global privacy regulations?

Are there any ways around this, maybe using TrustArc in a static way? 
More about TrustArc @ https://www.trustarc.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get TrustArc working within Salesforce by including the script within the Advanced -> Head Markup and ensuring the Allow Inline Scripts and Script Access to Any Third-party Host is set in the Security Preferences. Any Script that gets included in the Head Markup will be loaded and attached to the LockerService SecureWindow object allowing the script to manipulate the DOM as needed.